# elementary-theme package broken, how do I fix it?

Tags: 12.04, apt, 64-bit, package-management

I was trying to install `elementary theme` over unity in Ubuntu 12.04, parallel to my win7. Both are running fine till this mishap by me today. The apt-get couldn't install the dependencies hence crashed.

Now I tried to rectify with `sudo apt-get -f install` at one stage when i got this output:

```
[835:15] sources.list.d bash $ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  elementary-theme
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  elementary-theme
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/133 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,497 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 257956 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking elementary-theme (from .../elementary-theme_3.4->0~r649+pkg293~precise1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/elementary-theme_3.4->0~r649+pkg293~precise1_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Range/slider.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/elementary-theme_3.4-0~r649+pkg293~precise1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Now how can I sort this out as this is not giving me any chance to update the local installations?

**Update**:
@Jorge , my findings to your patch is as follows:

```
[849:6] ~ bash $ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/elementary-theme_3.4-0~r649+pkg293~precise1_all.deb
(Reading database ... 257950 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking elementary-theme (from .../elementary-theme_3.4-0~r649+pkg293~precise1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Range/slider.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Range/trough.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Range/slider-prelight.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Handle/dimple.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Handle/pane-horiz.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Handle/resize_grip.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Handle/pane-vert.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Sidebar/handle.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/right_slider_normal.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/breadcrumb_prelight.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/left_slider_normal.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/button/right_slider_normal_alt.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/button/left_slider_normal_alt.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/button/breadcrumb_prelight.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/button/breadcrumb_normal.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/old/right_slider_normal.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/old/breadcrumb_prelight.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/old/left_slider_normal.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/old/breadcrumb_normal.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/breadcrumb_normal.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/nautilus/extra-widget.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Button/normal.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Button/insensitive.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Button/mode_prelight.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Button/selected.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Button/prelight.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Button/mode_normal.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Button/mode_pressed.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/gtkrc', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Apps/steadyflow.rc', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Apps/xfce-panel.rc', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Apps/xfce-panel/panel-dark.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Icons/media-skip-forward.svg', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Icons/media-playback-pause.svg', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Icons/media-skip-backward.svg', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Icons/media-playback-start.svg', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-2.0/Icons/close.png', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/metacity-1/metacity-theme-3.xml', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/index.theme', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/assets/resize-grip.svg', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/assets/scale-slider.svg', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/assets/switch-slider.svg', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/assets/pane-handle.svg', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/assets/scale-slider-insensitive.svg', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/content-view.css', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/scrollbar.css', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/menu.css', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/settings.ini', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/gtk.css', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/progressbar.css', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/toolbar.css', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/scale.css', which is also in package elementary 3.1
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/button.css', which is also in package elementary 3.1
Setting up elementary-theme (3.4-0~r649+pkg293~precise1) ...
```

What am i doing wrong actually here ?

Comment: This is a bug of the package. Please report it as such. No package should try to overwrite files handles by others.

Comment: @gertvdijk This is a bug, but the question in effect asks about how to deal with a *general category of bugs* (packages that are not intended to conflict with each other--and thus not declared as conflicting--providing the same file). And it has [a good general answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/322622/22949). So we should possibly keep this open, for the general element which can be considered not to be a bug report. **NumanSyed**: It woul still be a good thing for you to [report the bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) (see also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121)).

Answer (score 1):

The package you downloaded is conflicting with another package. You can work around this by force installing the elementary-theme package.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/elementary-theme_3.4->0~r649+pkg293~precise1_all.deb
```

After that you might want to do a `sudo apt-get upgrade` to continue updating the other 45 packages.

Comment: Thanks for the info! But I have made it worse ! Using `Synaptic Package Manager` I have deleted 'elemetary-desktop' and 'elementary-xxxxxx`. However, I have tried your patch and found this:

Comment: Oops! Pressed `Enter` too early!

Comment: Thanks @[Eliah Khan](http://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan), I tried to report this when my system told me `The problem cannot be reported: This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again.` Any idea on this, anybody?

Comment: I got a solution and want to put it up here but askubuntu keep telling me my answer`appears to be spam`!